# Hibernate. org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:com.gontuseries.Student_Info

Tags: java, hibernate

I am following the Gontu series for Hibernate these but i get an exception as 
"org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:com.gontuseries.Student_Info"

here are my files:
Main.java

```
package com.gontuseries.hibernate;import org.hibernate.Session;import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    // Write the Student_Info object into the database
    Student_Info student = new Student_Info();
    student.setName("Gontu");
    student.setRoll_no(1);


    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    // this would save the Student_Info object into the database
    session.save(student);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close(); }}
```

then Student_Info.java

```
package com.gontuseries.hibernate;import javax.persistence.Entity;import javax.persistence.Id;import javax.persistence.Table;@Entity @Table(name="STUDENT_INFORMATION")public class Student_Info {
@Id 
private int    roll_no;

private String name;

public Student_Info() {

}

public Student_Info(String name, int roll_no) {

    this.name    = name;
    this.roll_no = roll_no;
}

public int getRoll_no() {
    return roll_no;
}

public void setRoll_no(int roll_no) {
    this.roll_no = roll_no;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}}
```

then HibernateUtil.java:

```
package com.gontuseries.hibernate;import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();

        serviceRegistry =  new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();


        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    } catch (Throwable ex) {

        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    return sessionFactory;
}}
```

then hibernate.cfg.xml (along with other code in this):

```
    <mapping class="com.gontuseries.hibernate.Student_Info"/>
```

Comment: could you please send project navigator screen shot and the screen shot of your configuration xml file ?

Comment: try to rebuild your project.